# Ideas for how to catch the last index in a jscript for loop, where lengh of index is is unknown?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Consider the following for loop (and assuming we don't know 3 times table - i.e. how many results might occur).

```
<script summary>
function myFunction() {
  var output_text = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    
    if (Number.isInteger(i/3)){
        if ("e.g. this is the last index?") {"e.g.then do this?"
        output_text += "This number is the last " + i ;
        }else{
        output_text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
        }
    }
  }
  
}
</script>
```

Trying to 'output_text' as something like: 
The number is 0 
The number is 3 
The number is 6 
The number is 9 
The number is 12 
The number is 15 
The number is the last 18

Any ideas for how to catch that last loop iteration.
This is just an example as actual application is a bit wordy - but the concept is the same.
I could run a count first to get index length, but wondered if there is an easier way.
Many thanks for anyone's time. Also first go at posting - any advice welcome.

Comment: Use `if (i % 3 == 0)` instead. This way you dont need to check for integer status. `%` means modulus or remainder.

Comment: But your question is misleading because your last index *is known* as defined in your for loop control line, conditionally.

Comment: inside the for loop after the if condition "if (Number.isInteger(i/3))" just check if(i + 3 > n) 'n' is 20 in your case, in that case you have your last index value

Comment: capture "good" results in an array, then iterate that array, and if iterator is one less than array's length, add "is the last"...

Comment: Many thanks all for time and suggestions. The maths example was just that, sorry if not clear enough.  iAmOren and Mukerram got  the idea of trying to catch last iteration if the number of 'good' results is unknown.  I'll experiment with that.  I Already have a solution by counting first, just not very elegant!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `3` to the current index and check if it exceeds `19`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var output_text = "";
  var i;
  const max = 19;
  const factor = 3;
  for (i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    if (i % factor === 0){
        if (i + factor > max) {
            output_text += "This number is the last " + i ;
        }else{
            output_text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
        }
    }
  }
  return output_text;
}
document.write(myFunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number divisible by 3, perform a second check to see if 20 minus `i` < 3 and you'll know if it's the last number.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var output_text = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {   
    if (Number.isInteger(i/3)){
      if (20 - i < 3) {
        output_text += "This number is the last " + i ;
      }else{
        output_text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = output_text;
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The better approach is to show result of current iteration in the next iteration. In this case, last iteration will not be handled in the loop. So, you can handle it after easily.